# При вызове fork(), дочерний процесс игнорирует выполнение функций

Tags: c++, http, unix, процесс

Пишу http-сервер, который обрабатывает запросы, открывая для каждого свой процесс. Решил переписать код, старый и новый код праткически идентичны, но в новом половина запросов игнорируются дочерним процессе

```
for(;;)
{
    client current(cone.get_socket());
    httpHandler worker(current.client_d());
    pid_t child = fork();
    if (child == 0)
    {
        httpParser a(current.client_d());
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
        worker.handle(a.data());
        std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
        _exit(0);
    }
    else if (child < 0)
        std::cout << "error fork" << std::endl;
}
```

я расставил cout, т.е процесс не подебажишь и обноружил, что не одни из coutов не выполняется. Это видно на скрине, в терминал выводится запрос, требущий обработки и после этого метки, которые я поставил 1 и 2 вы видите, а in внутри метода heandle. (при этом сам процемм открывается, если поставить какой нибудь вывод в самом начале, он выведет). Так же это код работает без fork

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

почему так происходит, этот код максимально упращен, чтоб найти ошибку,
вот рабочий вариант, но методы выполняют одну и ту же работу(упрастил потому что сложный вариант тем более не работал)

```
    for(;;)
    {
      client *current = client::listen_port(cone.get_socket());
      httpHandler worker(current);
      if (fork() == 0)
      {
      pollfd fds;
      for(;;)
      {
          fds.fd = current->get_client();
          fds.events = POLLIN;
          int ready = poll(&fds, 1, 100);
          if (ready > 0)
          {
             fds.events = 0;
             httpParser* temp = new httpParser(current->get_client());
             if (temp->get_recvByte() > 0)
                  worker.handle(temp);
             if (temp->get_recvByte() == 0)
             {
                  delete temp;
                  break;
             }
              if (temp->get_recvByte() < 0)
              {
                 std::cout << "error recv, fd: " << current->get_client() << endl;
                 delete temp;
              }

          }
          else
          {
               std::cout << "close 1\n";
              _exit(0); // если recv заблокировался на чтении и время ожидания истекло, мы закрываем процесс
          }

      }
       std::cout << "close 2\n";
      _exit(0); // если recv вернул 0, мы закрываем процесс
      }
    }
```

Comment: все дочерние процессы, кроме первого, просто игнорируют worker.handle(a.data());

Comment: Не зная, что конкретно делают с сокетом ваши объекты ничего дельного сказать нельзя (это же ООП, все важные для понимания сути происходящего детали заабстагированы и надежно спрятаны)